# PharmGKB diagrams; how do I convert them into customizable svgs?

Tags: svg, illustration

I'd like to be able to convert this pathway [(1)](https://www.pharmgkb.org/pathway/PA2039) to SVG in a way that I can then edit (e.g., adding a legend to the diagram and edit some of the hyperlinks in the diagram). I have tried saving it as PNG (e.g., by right-clicking the pathway [in Chrome] and clicking, "Save image as...") and then using Inkscape to save this as a SVG. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a link to a [PDF version of the pathway](https://www.pharmgkb.org/views/pathway/PA2039.pdf) in the right-hand sidebar. It looks like the diagram is embedded as a vector graphic in the PDF file, so you should be able to [convert it to SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10288065/convert-pdf-to-clean-svg) or open it with Inkscape.